# Can't move arm joints on the NAO

Tags: python, python-2.7, nao-robot

I am using NAOqi with Python to program my NAO robot. When I copy the code from the Python file [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/naoqi/motion/control-joint-api.html#ALMotionProxy::setAngles__AL::ALValueCR.AL::ALValueCR.floatCR) it works fine. I adjusted it to my variables like this:

```
nav.setStiffnesses("Head", 1.0)

names  = ["HeadYaw", "HeadPitch"]
angles  = [0.2, -0.2]
fractionMaxSpeed  = 0.2
nav.setAngles(names, angles, fractionMaxSpeed)

time.sleep(3.0)
nav.setStiffnesses("Head", 0.0)
```

but when I change it to use the arm joints it doesn't work:

```
nav.setStiffnesses("RArm", 1.0)

names  = ["RShoulderPitch"]
angles  = [0]
fractionMaxSpeed  = 1
nav.setAngles(names, angles, fractionMaxSpeed)

sleep(3.0)
nav.setStiffnesses("RArm", 0.0)
```

After during the code the arm is stiff and when it is done running it becomes limp but it doesn't move at all (I have tried different `fractionMaxSpeeds`).

I got all the joint angles and joint names from [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/family/robots/joints_robot.html#robot-joints).

Comment: you should look at the naoqi log, to see if errors are reported. from the robot shell: "qicli logview" or in the choregraphe log windows.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, after 3 seconds, you reset the stiffness to zero:

```
nav.setStiffnesses("RArm", 0.0)
```

Remove that line and the arm will remain stiff after running the code.